# A tricky geometry question

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I tried for more than an hour to solve the below problem but got nothing. I tried to make a copy and flip it vertically and attach it to the original shape but no more happened.
$AB=9,DC=16\\AO=OD$ [image]

This is half of a circle . I don't how apply $distance -of -A- to -circle=distance -of -B- to -circle$ as a result of $AO=OD$

Can someone help me to start to sloving,please?
Implicitly I tied two below figure
[image]

Comment: https://mindyourdecisions.com/blog/2021/01/02/interesting-puzzle-quadrilateral-and-a-semicircle/#more-33863

Comment: Watching the youtube linked in the comment of YouKnowMe, I find it very interesting that you can solve for $(r^2 + x^2)$, but can not solve for either $r$ or $x$.

Comment: @user2661923; thank you very much, you get the clue.+1

Comment: @user2661923: Is it your own page ? or are you "PRESH TALWALKAR" ? thank you again. I am interested in your page

Comment: I don't have a page.  I was curious, so I simply watched the youtube video referenced in the comment of YouKnowMe.  In that video, near the very end, it makes the point that both $r$ and $x$ can not be solved for.  Are you sure that you didn't mean to address your comment to YouKnowMe?

Comment: @user2661923,Thank you anyway. yes I got what you mean about $r,x,r^2+x^2$

Comment: your case is a special case of this problem https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1985_IMO_Problems/Problem_1#Problem

Comment: @endgame yourgame : I don't understand your reference: we haven't here a cyclic quadrilateral.